# hold specific pattern in symbolic calculation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I encounter some questions when I try to simplify a symbolic expression using Mathematica.
For example, I got an intermediate expression `a*(x^m)*(y^n)+b*(x^m)*(y^n)+c*(x^(m-1))*(y^n)+d*(x^(m-1))*(y^n)`. If I use `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`, Mathematica will give the results as `(x^(m-1))*(c+d+(a+b)x)*(y^n)`. But what I want is `(a+b)(x^m)(y^n)+(c+d)(x^(m-1)(y^n))`.
How can I realize such functionality? Shall use Pattern matching or something ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a job for [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html):

```
expr = a*(x^m)*(y^n) + b*(x^m)*(y^n) + c*(x^(m - 1))*(y^n) + d*(x^(m - 1))*(y^n);

Collect[expr, x, Factor]
(* (c + d) x^(-1 + m) y^n + (a + b) x^m y^n *)
```